# How declare subcategory java

Tags: java

I want to create a subcategory for this option. I can't create. When I select 1, I want it to show me a few subcategories.

```
package Javaapplication7;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class JavaApplication7 {

        static Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
        static ArrayList<Employee> emplList = new ArrayList<Employee>();

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            while(true) {

                System.out.println("1.Register employee");
                System.out.println("2View employee");
                System.out.println("3.Remove employee");
                System.out.println("4.Generate payslips");
                System.out.println("5.Exit");
                System.out.println("input option: ");
                int option = input.nextInt(); input.nextLine();



                switch(option){     
                    case 1:    
                        System.out.println("Register is selected ");
                        System.out.println("provide name: ");
                        String name = input.nextLine();
                        double salary= input.nextInt(); input.nextLine();
                        Employee emp = new employee(name,salary);
                        emplList.add(emp);
                        System.out.println("Regsitered:");
                }
            }
        }

}
```

So when I choose 1 I want to show 1 ... , 2 ... , 3 .... , 4....

Comment: Have you compiled your program yet?If,no,do it first and see what it says

Comment: it s working that but i dont know how carry on , i want to create a subcategory

Comment: So what’s wrong with your code ? You need to provide more explanation of your issue

Comment: it s nothing wrong here , i don t know how create an subcategory . here i create already an category but how can i create a subcategory  , like what next

Comment: So, selecting `1. Register Employee` should not only let us register a new employee, it should _also_ send us to an entirely other menu of different choices, rather than just returning us to the main menu?

Comment: yes that is the point

Answer (score 0):

However your program have so many typo and syntax error but its nice at least you done something and come up here with code.

this code is not so best but i think it will help you :)

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Test {
 static Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);


public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {



    int inputOption;
    do { 

        System.out.println("Choose Your Option :");
        System.out.println("1.Register employee");
        System.out.println("2. View employee");
        System.out.println("3.Remove employee");
        System.out.println("4.Generate payslips");
        System.out.println("5.Exit");
        System.out.println("input option: ");

       inputOption = input.nextInt(); 


       switch (inputOption) {
            case 1:


                System.out.println("Register is selected ");
                System.out.println("Do your Task"); 

                System.out.println("Choose Your Option :");
                System.out.println("1.Option 1");
                System.out.println("2.Option 2"); 
                System.out.println("5.Exit"); //keep 5 for exit
                System.out.println("input option: ");

                int inputSubOption = input.nextInt(); 

                switch (inputSubOption) {
                case 1:
                        System.out.println("1 Sub category Taks");
                        System.out.println("Press any number other then 5 to continue.....");
                        int exit = input.nextInt();
                        if( exit ==5 ) {System.exit(0); }
                    break;
                case 2:
                    System.out.println("2 Sub category Taks");
                break;

                default:
                    break;
                }

                break;

            default:
                break;
       }


    } while ( inputOption !=5 ) ;



}

}
```